# MYSQL Update Table 1 Column Based On Table 2's Column Value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Basic SQL update based on conditions of another table's col:

```
UPDATE table_1 
   SET col_value = '0' 
 WHERE tbl2_col_val IN 
        (SELECT tbl2_col_val 
           FROM table_2 
          WHERE tbl2_col_val = 'whatever')
```

The error I get is:

#1054 - Unknown column 'tbl2_col_val' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Everywhere I look I keep finding this same logic, but it doesn't work.  It's issue is after the first WHERE clause I believe.  [Here's one of my resources...seems pretty straight forward!](https://chartio.com/learn/sql-tips/how-to-update-a-column-based-on-a-filter-of-another-column/)

EDIT:

Wordpress Database.  A ton of posts were imported into a new build, that theme has a custom option (checkbox) for all posts.  The imported posts did not pick up the option and add the meta_value.  If I check the box, only then does that post get the meta_value of 1, unchecked sets that value to 0.  It's just an enum basically.  I have over 1400 posts and some need to be checked, others need to be unchecked.  I was able to run a function that auto checked all of them inside of functions.php, now I need to run an SQL update inside the DB to auto uncheck the others.  This is how the query looks using WP DB tables.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = '0' WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '993')
```

Comment: Please post the definitions for both tables.

Comment: ... and add table alias to EACH column name used.

Answer (score -2):

```
UPDATE table1 t1
JOIN table_2  t2 ON 
t2.tbl2_col_val IN (SELECT t2.tbl2_col_val FROM table_2 WHERE t2.tbl2_col_val = 'whatever')
SET t1.col_value = '0';
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: That updated all values inside t1.col_value to 0 unfortunately.

Comment: You have to keep the relation condition otherwise it updates all. For ex t1.pk_colname = t2.fk_col_name